# Why is values any[][]

Tags: office-js

I had a quick question regarding a design decision of office-js, specifically with Excel.

I recently had a bug whose root cause was around the dynamic nature of `any` in TypeScript (notably that type checking is just disabled with it). I had assumed that a value from `Excel.Range.values` was a `string` when really it was a `number`. This got me thinking: why is the type of values `any[][]`? The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/excel/excel.range?view=office-js#values) explicitly state that "the data returned could be of type string, number, or a boolean." To me, this indicates that a more correct type would be `(string | number | boolean)[][]`.

What were the reasons behind this decision?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a combination of a historical reason and a practical reason.

The **historical reason** is that when the `Range.values` API was first shipped circa 2016, there was no concept of type unions in TypeScript yet.  So the only way to describe "string or number or boolean" would have been with `any`.  And that making a change to something like `(string | number | boolean)[][]` would be a breaking change (lots of red squigglies, continuous integration breaking, etc.)

The **practical reason** is that even though `(string | number | boolean)[][]` is more accurate, it's not necessarily more usable.  Consider code that you could have written today, when values is typed as `any[][]`:

```
console.log(range.values[0][0] * 2);
```

If values were typed as `(string | number | boolean)[][]`, you would now get an error:

> The left-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any', 'number', 'bigint' or an enum type.

In most automation scenarios, I would argue that you already know what value you expect to get (i.e., the `range` in question may have been something where you previously wrote something to, and so you know it's a number).  But now you'd still need to explicitly cast the value:

```
console.log(range.values[0][0] as number * 2);
```

For my own personal preference, I would actually still bite the bullet and deal with the casting (i.e., I would still prefer the world of `(string | number | boolean)[][]`).  But combined with the historical reason, and that there are countless lines of code and countless repos that would suddenly be broken by this change, I think this is a change that would need to be rolled up as part of some larger breaking change with an explicit version number change, rather than something to just incrementally introduce in the d.ts.

Would love to hear your opinions if you think otherwise.

Comment: I didn't know about the historical reason (I'm brand new to typescript), that's a big one! I also agree with your assessment that the union would be slightly less usable in a lot of scenarios, but I would personally still prefer it. Maybe in 2.0 :) Great answer, thank you.